# Анимация css по кнопке js

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Сначала должен быть пусто фон,после нажатия на кнопку начать анимацию появляется квадрат и начинает вращаться,после нажатия на кнопку удалить анимацию удаляется этот квадрат и возращаеться пустой фон

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">


.square{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

</style>




</head>
<body>


 <div class="square"> </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

btn1=document.createElement('BUTTON');  // создание кнопки
btn1.id='cmd1';  // id кнопки
btn1.onclick = function(){ // функция при клике по ней
}
btn1.textContent ='начать анимацию'; // имя кнопки
document.body.appendChild(btn1); // нужно для добавления кнопки

btn2=document.createElement('BUTTON');  // вторая кнопка
btn2.id='cmd2';
btn2.onclick = function(){

}
btn2.textContent ='удалить анимацию'; // имя кнопки
document.body.appendChild(btn2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
btn1 = document.createElement('BUTTON');  // создание кнопки
btn1.id = 'cmd1';  // id кнопки
btn1.onclick = function () { // функция при клике по ней
 document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
btn1.textContent = 'начать анимацию'; // имя кнопки
document.body.appendChild(btn1); // нужно для добавления кнопки

btn2 = document.createElement('BUTTON');  // вторая кнопка
btn2.id = 'cmd2';
btn2.onclick = function () {
 document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
btn2.textContent = 'удалить анимацию'; // имя кнопки
document.body.appendChild(btn2);
```

```css
.square {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 background-color: #A52A2A;
 animation-name: spin;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 display: none;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
 <div class="square"> </div>
```